# Link targetting to iframe only works once, then opens in new tab

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

I have links with the following structure:

`<a href="jsp/site/MyJSPFile.jsp?identifier=identifier-with-only-alphanumeric-chars&name=someURLEncoded-UTF8-french-sentence-with-special-chars" target="my_iframe" class="text">My link text</a>`

The **name** parameter was recently added and is a string generated by URL encoding some French text using UTF-8.

Before adding this parameter the links used to work fine, they opened in the target iframe every time and I had no issues. Now since the name parameter has been added:

1. I click on the first link and the expected behaviour happens (link opens in the iframe, no error message whatsoever in the Network or Console panels)
2. I click on any other link of the same type, targetting the same iframe, **it opens in a new tab**.
3. Any link I click after that reproduces step 2.

I would like, obviously, every link to open in the iframe, which is not the case here.

This happens in Google Chrome and Firefox but weirdly, IE is working fine (links never open in new tabs when they shouldn't).

Any tips or clues would be greatly appreciated!